# External binary resource opened but not existing in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qresource

I have the following **main.qml** file:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Item
{
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    Label
    {
        id: textLabel
        anchors.fill: parent
        x: 200
        y: 400
    }

    CustomObject
    {
        id: customObjectId
    }
}
```

`CustomObject` is a `QML` file defined in an external binary resource, generated by the `rcc` command:

```
rcc -binary -o redTheme.qrc redTheme.rcc
```

**CustomObject.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Item
{
    Rectangle
    {
        width: 200
        height: 120
        color: "blue"
        Label
        {
            text: "customObject"
        }
    }
}
```

In the `C++` side, I register my resource like this:

```
QResource::registerResource(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/data/themes/redTheme.rcc");
```

The function returns `true`, which means the file is opened.

Yet, `CustomObject` does not exist in my **main.qml** file. Why?

`CustomObject is not a type`

**EDIT:** I've wrapped `CustomObject` into a `QML Module` and then compiled it into a `.rcc` file (it means the `qmldir` file is inside the `.qrc`). No difference whatsoever, `CustomObject` still isn't recognized as a type, even if I add an `import` statement (`import redTheme 1.0`). Content of my **qmldir** file:

```
module redTheme
CustomObject 1.0 CustomObject.qml
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically change QML theme at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335481/dynamically-change-qml-theme-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure, but I think QML files as types only works for "internal" QML files, that is the QML files that are in the internal resource file.

In order for external QML files to work as types, you need to have a valid QML module defined, with its `qmldir` file and such. It may also be possible to expose it as a type using the C++ API, but I haven't investigated it, basically, it is what the `qmldir` file parser does.

The other way to use external QML files is as path/url, that is, if you want it instantiated, you either need to use a `Loader` or manually instantiate it dynamically.

This might help to register external QML files as QML types:

`int qmlRegisterType(const QUrl &url, const char *uri, int versionMajor, int versionMinor, const char *qmlName)`

> This function registers a type in the QML system with the name
>   qmlName, in the library imported from uri having the version number
>   composed from versionMajor and versionMinor. The type is defined by
>   the QML file located at url. The url must be an absolute URL, i.e.
>   url.isRelative() == false.
>
> Normally QML files can be loaded as types directly from other QML
>   files, or using a qmldir file. This function allows registration of
>   files to types from C++ code, such as when the type mapping needs to
>   be procedurally determined at startup.

Comment: I intend to create a lot of themes which will be switchable at the user's will (example: user clicks on a button which switches between the blue theme and the red theme.) 

Thus, I don't think using `qmlRegisterType` is a good idea since I will end up with dozens/hundreds of additional lines of code.

I could integrate my `CustomObject` into a `QML Module`, but it is already inside a `.qrc` file. Isn't that a bit redundant?

Comment: Well, either you want to use a QML file as a typr or you don't which is it? In your code this is what you try to do, and registering a type is the only way to do it, either manually or with a `qmldir` file. As for the rest, it really depends what you mean by themes - just different dimensions and colors, or completely different UI structure?

Comment: Currently it's only dimensions and colors. I'll try with QML Module solution and keep you updated.

Comment: See updated original post. Doesn't seem to work. Should I externalize my qmldir?

Comment: @GrégoireBorel - a module will not work in a resource file, it needs to be out on the file system, also it needs to be in a valid import path, you can add import paths with `void QQmlEngine::addImportPath(const QString &path)`. But if it is only colors and dimensions, you can put a style in a simple json file, no need for anything fancy.

Comment: `QQmlEngine::addImportPath(const QString &path)` would force me to write the absolute paths of every themes in my **main.cpp** file. Since I don't want to compile my themes with my binary, I would have to copy them into my binary folder. Then, I would use `addImportPath`, but it would not be very flexible. Unless I can import all the themes with one statement?

Would you mind give more information about the `JSON` style sheet?

Comment: Or maybe have all your themes in a dedicated themes folder? It is not a JSON style sheet, just a JSON file with values for colors and dimensions, you can extra and apply to your UI files. There is nothing built in, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: This thread might be a duplicate with my other one (in which I give a solution to the whole problem): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335481/dynamically-change-qml-theme-at-runtime/36399339#36399339

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar effect with external rcc files. Try adding 'qrc' scheme to your url when loading qml files from external resources:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine("qrc:/main.qml");
```